# Does any one know meaning of alayina

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-countries

Does any one know meaning of **alayina** or **elaaina** i want to give this name to my daughter.

Comment: The concept of a Muslim name does not exist in Islam. Name your child whatever you wish but don't use anything offensive or blasphemous.

Answer (score 1):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, the Most Kind.

**Your question:** What is the meaning of elaaina?

**Answer:**

First of all, the name Elayna is a French baby name. In French the meaning of the name Elayna is: Shining light.

And as a girl's name is a variant of Elaine (Greek), and the meaning of Elayna is "sun ray, shining light".

It is permissible to use that name because it does not go against anything. The only thing is not permitted for you to put the name of your child is a pagan name for example if you use Zeus or Hera on your child then no, it haram. There’s a Hadith regarding the names which prophet Muhammad asked somebody what’s his name and he said.... and Muhammad told him/ her to change your name because there is only one true God.

**Your question:** What does it mean alayina?

**Answer:**

The name Alayna is an Irish baby name. In Irish the meaning of the name Alayna is: Beautiful. Dear child. This mean it also mean Princess in Arabic language.

**Conclusion:** these names are very beautiful and you can use them if you want to.